# calculate with decimal values

Tags: php, mysql

At the the moment, I stored values in my mysql database as a decimal value (199,54).
But If I get this value with php (mysql query) and would like to calculate with it:

```
echo ($row->myValue) / 5;
```

I get the error:

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered ...
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: _"Where is my mistake?"_ - in thinking `199,54` was an actual decimal value. The decimal separator in PHP as well as MySQL, is the dot, `.` The value you have there can only be a _text_ value.

Comment: What is the encode set into DB? In PHP the decimal separator is dot (.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `floatval` function to convert decimal value that is fetched from database and then you can use in calculation:

```
$floatValue =  floatval($row->myValue);
```

Now you can use `$floatValue` variable in any calculation.

Comment: If they really fetched the _text_ value `199,54` from their database, then applying floatval will result in just 199.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out decimal separator in php is dot (.) not comma (,).
Either change the separator on the DB level to . or run the following anytime you want to deal with numbers stored in the database. First two lines are just an example to get it running locally for me

```
<?php
    $row = new stdClass(); 
    $row->myValue = "15,29";    
    $myValue = str_replace(',', '.', $row->myValue) / 5;
    echo $myValue;
?>
```